# query with list of type

Tags: c#, generics, nhibernate

i have a list of type

```
List<Type> list = new List<Type>();
list.Add(typeof(class1))
list.Add(typeof(class2))
```

that contains a list of type that are nhibernate table.
class1 is a sql table as class2.

now i want a query like

```
int num = 0;
foreach (var item in list)
{                
    num += session.Query<item>().Count();
}
```

session is the ISession class.

the problem is with item, 'because is a variable but is used like a type'

how can i convert the type to the class?

Comment: i don't want an instance of the type in the list. the query expect the class

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the generic method via reflection:

```
int num = 0;
MethodInfo genericMethod = session.GetType().GetMethod("Query");
foreach (var item in list)
{   
    MethodInfo specificMethod = genericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(item);
    IQueryable result = (IQueryable)method.Invoke(session, new object[0]);
    num += result.Count();
}
```

This at first gets the `MethodInfo` for the generic `Query` method (maybe the name is not 100% correct, try it).
Then it creates a specifically typed `MethodInfo` by calling `MakeGenericMethod` with the current type in `item`.
This method can finally be invoked, and the returned `object` casted to your expected result type (I presumed that `Query` returns an `IQueryable`).